# Custom Record In NetSuite

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I am fairly new to NetSuite. We have created a Custom Record for Consolidated Invoice (CI) ( Same customer, Same Insight Community, Combine invoices and create a Consolidated Invoice to send out).

The design of this module is like this :

Custom Records:
Consolidated Invoice ( for the CI)
Fields :
Date,Amount, IC Number, Customer, CI ID, Subsidiary

Consolidated Invoice Child ( for the regular invoice)
Fields :
Date,Amount, IC Number, Customer, CI ID, Subsidiary, Currency, CI ID

Now, these two records together hold the data for Consolidated Invoice. Our issue is: The CI PDF should contains all the items from all the regular invoices its been made up of. I am not able to decide where to pull this items from, as we have not made them part of either of the records. I can add a items tab in the child form and may be fetch them? Any ideas please ? I also thought of a saved search on the fly to pull the items from the regular invoices. Is that a good idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I've done consolidated billing I make the child records the actual invoices. You should let the natural invoices process as normal and just use the Consolidated Invoice for customer communication.

Then in the script that creates the consolidated invoice:

```
var renderer = nlapiCreateTemplateRenderer();
renderer.setTemplate(templateBody.getValue());
...
//this uses a saved search for details because it allows admins to add new columns without having to script
var invResults = nlapiSearchRecord('invoice', invSearch, new nlobjSearchFilter('custbody_ci_parent', null, 'is', ciInternalId));
if (invResults) renderer.addSearchResults('invTrans', invResults);
```

and then in your template:

```
<#list invTrans as tran>...</#list>
```

Comment: Hi bknights, thank you so much for your response. I am doing the exact same stuff ( such a relief to read your code). The part where we access invResults in freemarker template is not working for me at all.

Comment: I set the savedsearch results as below : renderer.addSearchResults('results',results); In the freemarker, when I try to access the values as below, nothing prints ! <#list invTrans as tran>${tran.id}</#list>. I am also setting a record of CI before I set the saved search as below:  renderer.addRecord('record', consInvoice); 
renderer.addSearchResults('invTrans',invResults); This should not be a problem, right ?

Comment: If you are adding the results as addSearchResults('results', results) then your freemarker template would need to be <#list results as tran>

The order you add things shouldn't matter as long as all the names are unique.